# Solving three matrix equations in three matrix variables

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

I have recently come across this system of three matrix equations in three unknown with three matrix unknowns (all matrices are real):

> We define the matrix $ X $ a square positive definite matrix and the matrix $Y$ as a rectangular real matrix, and $ \alpha > 0 $ is a positive constant, we have the three equations:
>
> $ -B^tX +B^tBAX + \alpha [C^tCAX-C^tY] = 0 $
>
> $ -XA^t + BAXA^t = 0 $
>
> $ CAXA^t -YA^t = 0 $

Where the variables are $ A,B,C $ (we assume dimensions allow multiplication) and we wish to solve for $ A,B,C $ generally. If we assume all three matrices are square and invertible, we may simply solve directly, and yet generally I have no clue on this. Perhaps the pseudoinverse will work here, but I cannot figure out how, also I figured may it is to do with eigenvalue problems, but again I cannot figure it out, maybe matrix decomposition but still I cannot see how. I certainly appreciate all help on this.

Comment: 1) Can you tell us the context of this problem ? 2) It's very doubtful that there is a solution. Maybe, you could try to write these equations using  Kronecker product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the unknowns real matrices are $A\in M_{p,n},B\in M_{n,p},C\in M_{q,p}$ and the known real matrices are $X\in M_n,Y\in M_{q,n}$.

There is the trivial solution $CAX=Y,BAX=X$, that implies $CA=YX^{-1},BA=I_n$.

Necessarily $n\leq p,rank(A)=rank(B)=n$, otherwise this trivial solution does not exist. Let $A\in M_{p,n}$ be any matrix with $rank(A)=n$.

Then $A^+=(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ and we can write $B,C$ as functions of $A$:

$B=A^++W(I_p-AA^+)$ where $W$ is any matrix in $M_{n,p}$.

$C=YX^{-1}A^++Z(I_p-AA^+)$ where $Z$ is any matrix in $M_{q,p}$.

EDIT. If $rank(A)=n$, then $A^T$ is a surjection and, necessarily, $BAX=X,CAX=Y$.

If $rank(A)<n$, then it is more difficult. For example, if $A=0$, then $B^TX+\alpha C^TY=0$ and we obtain $B$ as a function of $C$.

Comment: Thanks for the lovely answer, do you believe we may go one step beyond this trivial solution?